# Add ability to collapse expanded chat messages

Tags: feature-request, chat

When somebody dumps a wall of code in chat it is automatically shortened and a "(see full text)" link is added which expands the code block.

[image: codewall gonna codewall]

However once clicked there is no way (besides refreshing chat or dicking around in the dev console) to collapse said (unformatted) wall of code anymore.

[image: FUCK YOU MONGOLIANS ALWAYS TRYING TO BREAK DOWN MY SHITTY WALL]

My suggestion is to add a link somewhere to collapse the wall of code again. Either by a link underneath it or as an extra icon in the `<span class="meta">` element (the thing with the flag, star and reply icons).

Comment: And simply hitting F5 (or whatever the reload webpage button is on your box) isn't an option for you?

Comment: As I stated in my question that is an option. However that's like having to restart your car engine to turn off your lights again.

Comment: This please. ​​

Comment: Also, should the code snippet collapse when the page refreshes? Would it be better if it remained open?

Comment: @misterManSam Not if you don't have the ability to close it otherwise.

Comment: Well, of course :) if there was a solution to collapse / uncollapse *then* it should remain in the same state on page refresh.

Comment: It's not restricted to code. After enough lines (looks like per site setting) the message is clipped, e.g. http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2272049#2272049

Comment: @rene Was that trolling? I think it was trolling.

Comment: @Chris I'm always trolling...

Comment: Whoever's voting to close this as a duplicate of [Request: folding for code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268297/request-folding-for-code) please stop. This is about chat, not the main site. They're different questions.

Answer (score 18):

During the 6-8 weeks this takes to implement, see if this userscript can help you (tested in [The Sandbox on MSE Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/651/sandbox) and [Sandbox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox) with IE11/Win7, Chrome 36.0/Win7, FF31.0/Win7, Opera 12.16/Win7, Safari 7.1 but I'm open for bug reports).

```
/*global  $:false */
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var fullText = '(see full text)',
        collText = '(collapse)';

    $('#chat').on('click', 'a.more-data', function () {
        var mid = $('#message-' +
                this.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, this.href.length) +
                ' > div.content'),
            partCont = mid.children('.partial').html(),
            state = 0,
            fullCont,
            target,
            collapse;

        function toggle(o) {
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                target = mid.children('.full');
                fullCont = target.html();
                collapse = mid.children('a.my-toggle');
                state = 1;
                toggle(o);
                break;
            case 1:
                target.html(partCont);
                collapse.text(fullText);
                state = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                target.html(fullCont);
                collapse.text(collText);
                state = 1;
                break;
            }
            o.preventDefault();
        }

        mid.append($('<a />')
            .attr('href', '#')
            .addClass('my-toggle')
            .text(collText)
            .click(toggle));
    });
}());
```

<sub>[Opera 12.16 tested by Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2246344/sam)</sub>
<sub>[Safari 7.1 tested by AstroCB](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3366929/astrocb)</sub>